# Telerik RadAjaxManager loads controls slow the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

So I have a RadPanelBar, and within that a RadTreeView. On a node click event I want so update some control.. for now I am just trying to update a textbox. It works fine except that the first time I click on a child node it takes a very long time to update the control.. Just a simple text change. I set a break point in my function and I noticed that it is taking long to fire the OnNodeClick event.. If I click a parent node in the tree view it loads fine on the first click. Also, after the first time I've clicked it.. it loads quickly.. If I refresh the page, it is slow on the first click again.. Is there something I am missing.. Is the structure of my HTML inappropriate for these AJAX calls? I feel like this is a really simple example that should work..

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="IncidentReportPanel">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="IRViewPanel" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="LoadingPanel1" runat="server" Style="width: 320px;
    padding-top: 125px;" Skin="Vista">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<table width="100%">
    <tr style="height: 25px">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 100%">
        <td style="width: 250px">
            <telerik:RadPanelBar ID="IncidentReportPanel" runat="server" Height="450px" CssClass="IRPanel">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadPanelItem runat="server" Text="Incident Reports" ImageUrl="./Images/folder.gif"
                        Value="IncidentReports">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadPanelItem>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <telerik:RadTreeView ID="IncidentReportsTreeView" runat="server" OnNodeExpand="LoadTreeNodes"
                                        OnNodeClick="PopulateIRData">
                                        <Nodes>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Pending" ExpandMode="ServerSideCallBack" ImageUrl="./Images/completed.gif">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                            <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Completed" ExpandMode="ServerSideCallBack" ImageUrl="./Images/completed.gif">
                                            </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                                        </Nodes>
                                    </telerik:RadTreeView>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                    <telerik:RadPanelItem runat="server" Text="Calendar" ImageUrl="./Images/calendar.gif"
                        Value="Calendar">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadPanelItem>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <telerik:RadCalendar runat="server" ID="IRCalendar" Width="100%" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadPanelItem>
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadPanelBar>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Panel ID="IRViewPanel" runat="server">
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadText" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadTextBox>
            </asp:Panel>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
        protected void PopulateIRData(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        RadText.Text = "Hello, World!";
    }
```

EDIT: I updated my code according  to this article, http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-client-side-performance.html , and the problem persisted... again it only happens the first time..

EDIT: Just to clarify, by updating according to that article, I mean that I removed all the tables and relative widths and replaced them with css positioning and fixed widths.. the problem only happens the first time.. and it only happens sometimes.. quite a few times i thought i solved the problem as it would start responding quickly.. but then after I change my .aspx and change it back (even to the exact same thing when it was working quickly).. I get the same problem..

EDIT: So, I removed the AJAX component.. and setup the control so that it does a PostBack.. and it still takes long to hit my break point.. so it seems that its not an AJAX issue... but for some reason my events are taking long to fire..

EDIT:
So I followed the advice on this post and I used the webservices to do my binding and handle everything from the client side code.. All seemed to be ok until I decided that I wanted to return nodes from my webservice that could also be expanded.. So in my webservice I set the ExpandMode of my RadTreeNodeData object to Webservice.. and it renders the data correctly when I expand the child nodes.. However now I see the same problem from before where some calls take 20-30 seconds.. It takes 20-30 seconds to even hit the break point in my webservice.. Should I use the OnClientNodeExpand event instead? I don't understand why this is so slow!! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it fast all of the other times, and by fast I mean of an acceptable speed.

Comment: It's slow only the first time it load. All other times it is a very acceptable speed. If I refresh the page, it is slow the first time again.. then fast all other times after.

Comment: I really need to get this working.. opening up my first bounty.. hoping for some good suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [OnClientNodeClicked](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tree_clientonclientnodeclicked.html) and then you can update the controls client side.  If you need more data from the server you can call a web service from the client code.  Otherwise, to speed this up I would probably have to see your whole page and look at what requests are being sent back and forth.  Perhaps you have a lot of viewstate that is getting serialized or something.

Comment: What I posted is pretty much all my code... I pretty much have nothing in the viewstate.. do you have any tests you can recommend I do to try to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the fastest solution is to use a web service for binding. The standard AJAX functionality will still send ViewState and other flotsome across the wire that isn't necessary. You can find more here [TreeView / Load on Demand Modes](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/programming/loadondemandmodes/defaultcs.aspx) . So, your tree view would look something like the following where you would create an ASMX or WCF service that retrieves the nodes (in this case the LoadNodes method on the service at Default.asmx).

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="IncidentReportsTreeView" runat="server" >
    <WebServiceSettings Path="Default.asmx" Method="LoadNodes" />
</telerik>
```

Comment: I agree that this would be faster.. but it still shouldn't take 10-12 seconds to hit my breakpoint right? I will consider the webservices but I would still like to know why it's so slow... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the content in an UpdatePanel to see if the EnablePartialRendering makes any difference?  Not sure if the RadAjaxLoadingPanel makes a difference

How many elements are in the tree?

Comment: I see delays with as little as 4 elements in the tree. I will try the update panel thing and let you know!